# EntityFramework only call save changes if something has changed

Tags: entity-framework

When I edit entities using EF6, the code in my service layer looks something like:

```
    public bool EditPatient(Patient patient)
    {
        db.Entry(patient).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
```

Is there a way to only make the SaveChanges call if the patient's object fields have actually changed?

This gets called everytime someone presses save on the edit page, even if someone presses save without making any changes.

This doesn't work because when I retrieve and make changes to the patient object, retrieving the existing patient reflects those changes. So it always sees `patient == existingPatient`. It looks like its caching it somewhere before saving the changes to db.

```
     var existingPatient = db.Patients.Where(x => x.PatientId == patient.PatientId).First();
            if (patient != existingPatient)
            {
                var patientHistory = Mapper.Map<PatientHistory>(patient);
                patientHistory.UserId = UserId;
                patientHistory.ChangeType = "Edited";
                CreatePatientAudit(patientHistory);

                db.Entry(patient).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: Get entity from db and compare.